# PL/SQL - Numeric or Value Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Oracle is giving me the error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 15
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

```
DECLARE
idnumber NUMBER(10);
initials VARCHAR2(100);
userid VARCHAR2(100);
old_initials VARCHAR2(100);
CURSOR cursor1 IS
SELECT  s_first, s_last FROM tst_student ORDER BY s_first;
student cursor1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
FOR student IN cursor1 LOOP
idnumber :=1;
old_initials := SUBSTR(student.s_first,1,1) || SUBSTR(student.s_last,1,1);
initials := SUBSTR(student.s_first,1,1) || SUBSTR(student.s_last,1,1);
IF initials = old_initials THEN
userid := old_initials || '00' || idnumber + 1;
ELSE idnumber := 1;
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(userid);
END LOOP;
END;
```

The line it is complaining about is userid := old_initials || '00' || idnumber + 1;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to this:

```
userid := old_initials || '00' || (idnumber + 1); -- use brackets around the calculation
```

The problem is Oracle is trying to add the concatenated text to the number `1`, ie Oracle is parsing your original line as `userid := (old_initials || '00' || idnumber) + 1`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my error but it still isn't adding to my value. I am trying to get it to assign user id's to the students. It is just assigning 001 to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `user_id` is numeric field, use `to_number` to convert the string to number as:

```
 userid := to_number(old_initials || '00' || (idnumber + 1));
```

If it is `varchar` type the,

```
 userid := old_initials || '00' || (idnumber + 1);
```

**EDIT**: To increment, for NUMBER:

```
  idnumber := idnumber +1;
  userid := to_number(old_initials || '00' ||idnumber );
```

For VARCHAR:

```
 idnumber := idnumber +1;
 userid := old_initials || '00' || idnumber + 1;
```

**EDIT1**: Corrected segment:

```
  idnumber :=1;
  old_initials := '';
  FOR student IN cursor1 LOOP
    initials := SUBSTR(student.s_first,1,1) || SUBSTR(student.s_last,1,1);
    IF initials = old_initials THEN
      idnumber := idnumber +1;
      userid := old_initials || '00' || idnumber;
     ELSE 
      idnumber := 1; 
      old_initials := initials;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(userid);
   END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: @user1834591 You are not changing the value of your variable `idnumber` anywhere. Please refer the updated answer.

Comment: Thank for your help Yogendra. For some reason it still isn't increasing with the idnumber := idnumber+1; Maybe my other code is not correct?

Comment: @user1834591: You were assigning `idnumber` with `1` insode the loop in each iteration. That statements should be moved out of the `FOR` loop. Please refer the updated answer.

Comment: @user1834591 There is another bug in the code. Currently, `old_initials` and `initials` will always be equal, so the numbering will not restart when the initials change.

Comment: @user1834591: Please check the updated answer to handle the old initials comparison. If you think this is helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.